# My route includes image file requests when I don't specify a controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm building a site where I want to have only one controller, and url's that look like:

```
\main-page\sub-page
```

`main-page` is *not* the controller, and `sub-page` is *not* the action, they're just the names of pages in the database, which I want to render on the fly.  In other words, there are many pages, and I wouldn't want to make a controller for each one.  In fact, I want just one `Home` controller with one `Index` action that looks like this:

```
Function Index(ByVal Page As String, ByVal SubPage As String) As ActionResult
```

And there's only one view, which uses the parameters to dynamically load the page content.

The following route *almost* works:

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default", _
        "{page}/{subpage}", _
        New With {.controller = "Home", .action = "Index", .page = "Landing", .subpage = "Index"}
    )
```

But the problem is that it's also picking up requests for files, e.g., `/images/somefile.jpg`,  because that matches the route.

So the question is: how can I do this without also incorrectly getting the image requests OR is there a totally different way to do the route to support what I'm trying to do?

Comment: If there is file on this path, it should be returned before routing mechanism kicks in and that is how it works by default, so I would search for a solution somewhere else. Routing mechanism will only handle path if file doesn't exist in this path.

Comment: Now that you mention it, it does seem like the file requests are for files that don't exist, but that's bad too, because then instead of getting a missing image in the page, the whole page crashes (because the app looks in the database for a page that doesn't exist).  Also, I'm sure the browser does something different for an image that returns a 404 than one that returns some ASP.NET error.  So I guess the next question is: how do I deal with this new problem?

Comment: route.IgnoreRoute() for static resource paths is probably the way to go here

Answer (score 0):

Could you maybe try to ignore the route i.e.

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{*alljpg}", new {alljpg=@".*\.jpg(/.*)?"});
```

This is based on this [article](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/07/14/make-routing-ignore-requests-for-a-file-extension.aspx) which is probably more helpful than this brief post.

Well it's not a complete guess to be honest. I had a related problem with the favicon causing additional requests. The below code solved it so the principal is sound

```
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{*favicon}", new { favicon = @"(.*/)?favicon.ico(/.*)?" });
```